# How to correctly hide base method

Tags: c#, oop

What i have

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public new CustomUrlHelper Url { get; set; }

    public UrlHelper UUrl { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        Url = new CustomUrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);           

        UUrl = new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);

    }
}

public class CustomUrlHelper : UrlHelper
{
    public CustomUrlHelper(RequestContext requestContext) : base(requestContext)
    {
    }

    public CustomUrlHelper(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection) : base(requestContext, routeCollection)
    {
    }

    public string Action(string actionName)
    {
        return this.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, null, null);
    }
}
```

need to write a condition like that

```
if (true){Url = new CustomUrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);}
else{Url = new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);}
```

BUT:

how to organize cast or hides, because this construction does not make sense

```
 public new UrlHelper Url { get; set; }

 Url = new CustomUrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext) as UrlHelper;
```

call only Child constructor but not a method

UPD: Base method `Action` is not `virtual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is just `Url = new CustomUrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);`

if you only need a single instance of a UrlHelper per CustomViewWebPage, you've made it overly complicated. The benefit of inheritance is that the child IS a parent, for all intents and purposes. In your case, a CustomUrlHelper IS a UrlHelper, so you don't need both. Use this:

```
    public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
    {
        public UrlHelper Url { get; set; }

        public override void InitHelpers()
        {
            if (true){Url = new CustomUrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);}
            else{Url = new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);}

        }
    }
```

You don't need to cast a `CustomUrlHelper` to a `UrlHelper`, because it already is one (through inheritance).

You should also change the signature of your new Action method to `public override string Action(string actionName)`.

[image]

Edit: This is applicable for .NET 4.5. If you're looking to hide instead of override for .NET 4, then leave off the override modifier. You will still call your method the same way, and if your implentation is a CustomUrlHelper then it will call your custom version instead of the base method.

Comment: But 'Action' method in base class is no `virtual` - you example doesn't work.

Comment: What UrlHelper are you using ? In System.Web.Mvc it certainly is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504960(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: but in metadata it look like this public string `Action(string actionName, object routeValues);`

Comment: Ah, sorry... looks like it's virtual in .NET 4.5 but not in 4, that's probably why you see it as not virtual.